# How to see a new workflow for user belonging only to a custom role in OpenIDM?

Tags: openidm

I have a created a custom role `MyRole` in OpenIDM. I have also created a new user `User1` and a simple workflow. If `User1` has roles `MyRole` and any of the in-built roles like `Administrator/User/Task Manager` then we can login to the OpenIDM console as `User1` and able to see the new workflow on the dash board.
But, if the `user1` has is associated with only the new role `MyRole` , then the workflow is not visible on the OpenIDM console for `User1` login.

Can someone please explain me why I am not able to see the workflows using a user with only a custom role? How my custom role is different than that of the inbuilt roles? Any config files to be updated for mapping of custom roles and in-built roles?

Thanks.

Comment: I should actually tag it to OpenIDM but it is not yet available and I do not have sufficient points to create one. So, I am adding OpenAM tag.